# how to use firebase cloud function to delete firebase DB data on specific date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am making an app and having an issue in deleting firebase DB using cloud function on specific date.

[image]

This is how I am storing data , I want to delete this Node on nextDonationDate , I search a lot and found this can be done with cloud function, but I did not know how to do and access this because dates are saving under UserID of user so facing problem to make ref for that and how can I solve my problem to perform execution on nextDonationDate? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be the cloud function code will be something like this :

```
exports.deleteByDate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  //url example 
  //   deletebydate?date=Oct 28, 2017
  var targetDate = req.query.date;

  var db = admin.database();
  var donorDbRef = db.ref('Blood_donors_last_donation_date');
  var updateVal = {};

  donorDbRef
      .orderByChild('nextDonationDate')
      .equalTo(targetDate)
      .once('value')
      .then( snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
           updateVal[childSnapshot.key] = null
        });
        donorDbRef.update(updateVal, (error)=>{
           if(!error)
             res.status(200).send('succeed deleting data!');
           else
             res.status(200).send('failed deleting data!');                 
        });
      });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a tutorial on Youtube where they showed how to schedule a Cron Job for a cloud function trigger.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA

You can have this Cron running at regular intervals which will perform an HTTP call to your function. Here you can loop through all the nodes and checking the nextDonationDate as per your logic and delete the nodes which match your criteria.

You can optimize as per your requirement, this is a rough way to do this as i don't exactly know what and why you need to do something.

Comment: Thanks @Kushan for answering my question .... actually i am showing last donation date on list if available on DB .... if no data available on DB with child ref of UserId than showing Available else showing its last donation date.